# Open a directory in a new window in Python QT

Tags: python, pyqt4, qfiledialog

Hi i want to open a new window by a python QT code . Currently I am trying QFileialog getOpenFileName and getExistingDirectory however none of them is working as desired . Need to just open a new window with the given path .

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import sys

class OpenDir(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
         super(OpenDir, self).__init__()
         self.openDirectory()

    def openDirectory(self):
        print "Hi i am openDirectory Function . I will open Directory selected "
        openDirectoryDialog=QtGui.QFileDialog()
        #oD=openDirectoryDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"open","C:/")   # open file name
        oD=openDirectoryDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"open","C:/")  #Selectes folder


        if len(oD) > 0:
            print "accepted"
        else:
            print "nothing selected"


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui=OpenDir()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
#Function Main END

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like you need to `show()` your main window:

```
    ui=OpenDir()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and then maybe add a button for opening the dialog:

```
class OpenDir(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
         super(OpenDir, self).__init__()
         self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Open', self)
         self.button.clicked.connect(self.openDirectory)
         self.setCentralWidget(self.button)
```

Comment: Try running the code , it will open up a dialog box for you with C Drive and select folder button below . I want to open a window showing all directories of C Drive . Something like which we get in windows when we right click on a folder and click on Open in New window .

Comment: @paarthbatra. You mean you want to open a file manager with the path returned by the dialog?

Comment: I want to open a browser in windows with given path to Dialog .

Comment: did you understand my requirement ,please suggest if not ?

Comment: @paarthbatra. I think you are not explaining very well you want. Your previous comment seems to be saying that you want to open the path to a folder in a web-browser, which doesn't make any sense to me. I also don't understand why `QFileDialog` doesn't do what you want, since it allows you to browse files and directories just like a file manager.